# Bibiliography with elsarticle

Tags: natbib, elsarticle

If I use elsarticle  as follows, then pdf latex launched the errors.
Can I use the the follwoing commands for bibliography?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
　\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
 　\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
　\usepackage{usebib}
```

**Error**

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./elsarticle-template-num-names.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(./elsarticle-template-num-names.spl)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty))

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22    \bibliographystyle
                          {unsrt}
```

---

According to the answer of @Mico , I modified the codes and it works fine!!

```
 %\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,square,numbers,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
%\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{usebib}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.
```

This is happening because (a) the `elsarticle` document class loads `natbib` by default and (b) `natbib` is loaded again in the preamble, this time with the options `square`, `numbers`, and `sort&compress`. Since `natbib` was loaded initially *without* any options, the instruction `\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` is responsible for the option clash.

The remedy is to include the `natbib`-relevant options in the argument of the `\documentclass` instruction:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,square,numbers,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```